# Can I simplify in function column_default use of queries

Tags: wp-query, wp-list-table

In below function column_default I have several cases doing almost the same query.

Is it possible to use only 1 query for all the 3 cases? 
And if so how do I use it in below example?
Thanks for helping me.

```
function column_default($item, $column_name){
        global $wpdb;

 /*             
  if ( ! in_array( $column_name, ['id', 'user_id', 'user_email', 'answer', 'answer_time', 'ip_address' ] ) )
    return '';

$sql = "SELECT $column_name as result 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rdp_participants_answers 
        WHERE user_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

$query = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $item[ 'ID' ] ) );

if ( is_object( $query ) )
    return $query->result;
    */      
    switch($column_name){
//      case 'id':              return $item['ID'];
    case 'user_id':             return $item['ID'];
    case 'user_email':          $user_info = get_userdata($item['ID']);
                                return $user_info->user_email;
    case 'display_name':        $user_info = get_userdata($item['ID']);
                                return $user_info->display_name;            
    case 'city':                return get_user_meta($item['ID'], 'city', true);
    case 'age':                 return get_user_meta($item['ID'], 'age', true);

    case 'user_status':             $user_status = get_user_meta($item['ID'], 'status', true);

            if($user_status == 1) { 
                return '
                <img src="'.RDP_URL.'images/icon_status_green.gif" />
                <a href="'.get_admin_url().'admin.php?page=rdp_admin_participants&off='.$item['ID'].'&status=update"><img src="'.RDP_URL.'images/icon_status_red_light.gif" /><a/> 
                '; } 
                elseif($user_status == 0) { 
                return '<a href="'.get_admin_url().'admin.php?page=rdp_admin_participants&on='.$item['ID'].'&status=update"><img src="'.RDP_URL.'images/icon_status_green_light.gif" /><a/> 
                <img src="'.RDP_URL.'images/icon_status_red.gif" />';
            }
    case 'answer':                  
            $arrAnswer = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT answer FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rdp_participants_answers WHERE user_id = ".$item['ID']." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 " );
                    if(count($arrAnswer) == null)
                    return 0;
                    else
                    return $arrAnswer->answer;  
    case 'answer_time':         
            $arranswerTime = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT answer_time FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rdp_participants_answers WHERE user_id = ".$item['ID']." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 " );
                    if(count($arranswerTime) == null)
                    return 0;
                    else
                    return $arranswerTime->answer_time; 
    case 'ip_address':          
            $arrIPAddress = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT ip_address FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rdp_participants_answers WHERE user_id = ".$item['ID']." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 " );
                    if(count($arrIPAddress) == null)
                    return 0;
                    else
                    return $arrIPAddress->ip_address;   
    case 'user_registered': return $item['user_registered'];
    case 'actions':                 return $item[$column_name];
    default:                        return '<a href="'.get_admin_url().'admin.php?page=rdp_admin_participants&edit_rdp='.$item['ID'].'" class="page-title-action">Edit</a><a href="'.get_admin_url().'admin.php?page=rdp_admin_participants&view_rdp='.$item['ID'].'" class="page-title-action">View</a>'; 
    }
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users AS usr 
        JOIN wp_usermeta AS meta ON meta.user_id = usr.ID 
        LEFT JOIN wp_rdp_participants_answers as ans ON ans.user_id = usr.ID
        WHERE ans.answer IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY usr.ID, usr.user_email ORDER BY ans.id ASC";               


$data = $wpdb->get_results($query,ARRAY_A);
$this->items = $data;
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But how is that a WP problem?

Comment: It is not a problem getting the right data. But for me it seems very complex coding todo almost the same queries more then once. 
How can I get it per return in 1 query?

Comment: This seems to be unspecific to WordPress and likely better asked at another site of the network, such as [so].

Comment: This is pure WP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is mostly just a change in PHP logic, not really WordPress. Anyway, we are here to help, and that would be off-topic on other sites too, so …

1. It is unfortunate enough that you have to access a global variable in order to use the current database connection. Make others (you in 6 months!) life easier, and **import global variables always at the top of a function body.**

   If you are searching later for all accesses to that variables, you will thank your past self for that. :)
   In my code, I use mostly class methods as callbacks, and I pass the `$wpdb` object as a dependency into the class constructor, so I have to touch that global variable just *once*, at the very top of my code hierarchy.
2. When you are using *almost* the same query every time, look what the differences are, and make those either a variable, or unify them. In your case, you can just use the `$column_name` variable, because it is matching the database table column name and a **whitelist of valid strings**. Also, you can *rename* the resulting variable: `SELECT x as foo FROM …`
3. `$item[ 'ID' ]` is unknown, it can be anything. Always **prepare unknown values before you send them to the database**. `$wpdb` has method `prepare()` that works similar to `sprintf()`.
4. You don't need to run `count()` on the query result. You get an object only on success, so the faster test against `is_object()` is good enough.
5. Move that code to a **separate function**. It does too much.

Sample code for all of these points:

```
function answer_query( $column_name, $id )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT %s as result
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}rdp_participants_answers
            WHERE user_id = %d ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

    $query = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $column_name, $id ) );

    if ( is_object( $query ) )
        return $query->result;

    return 0;
}
```

And in your `switch` statement, shorten the code to:

```
case 'answer':
case 'answer_time':
case 'ip_address':
    return answer_query( $column_name, (int) $item['ID'] ) );
```

Comment: Just add it as extra function + added the shorten cases exactly as you wrote. As result I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function answer_query()

Comment: Well then you haven't declared the function at the proper place.